# Loading IE Cookies into Perl's WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, cookies, authentication, internet-explorer-9

I'm having a heck of a time with this...

I am trying to connect to a website which requires a login. I can obviously go directly to the page without logging in because IE has a cookie to do so.

I am working on a script that will be run by people other than myself, so I don't want to send around a file with my login information. Ideally, others wouldn't have to put that information in as well.

Here is the small, relevant part of the code. I just want to load the cookies from IE and print them (since I assume once they are in there, they will be accessed properly).

I've searched for hours and have even read people claim that this loads cookies. I see it being able to store cookies now, but not load existing cookies on my computer.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies::Microsoft;
use Win32::TieRegistry(Delimiter => "/");

my $cookies_dir = $Registry-> {"CUser/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/Shell Folders/Cookies"};
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies::Microsoft->new(file => "$cookies_dir\\index.dat",'delayload'=>0,);
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(cookie_jar => $cookie_jar);
print "Set Cookie Jar?\n", $cookie_jar->as_string, "\n";
print "Set Cookie Jar?\n", $mech->cookie_jar->as_string, "\n";
```

Can I load existing cookies?

Is [`HTTP::Cookies::Microsoft`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Cookies/lib/HTTP/Cookies/Microsoft.pm) not compatible with IE9? (Website lists IE6 and IE7, but hasn't been updated since 2002).

I don't even see where in this example or any example it actually LOADS existing cookies. If it is just a compatibility issue, what options are there for IE9? (I have to stick to IE9 since it is the support browser in this company)

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of `HTTP::Cookies::Microsoft` are you using? I found 6.00/6.01 which lists IE 5 and 6, but was last updated in 2011.

Comment: That would have been a nice issue. I'm using 6.00 apparently. I used CPAN to install.

Comment: I've looked at my win7 cookie dir, there is no `index.dat` file there. There only are a bunch of text files that seem to hold one or more cookies each. I hardly ever use IE, so that might be the issue. The code of the module looks like it only reads that .dat file, though.

Comment: I'll admit that I put `index.dat` there because I saw it in a few examples. I too do not have `index.dat` and infact have no `.dat` files. That line is one of the reasons that I wonder how it possibly loads cookies when it references a file that doesn't exist. Also, referencing the randomly generated names doesn't seem like an good idea either.

Comment: I'd try to read up on how the new IE saves those cookies and maybe build something on top of `HTTP::Cookies` myself. Did you try to just use the `HTTP::Cookies::Microsoft` module with the cookies dir and no file name? Maybe it figures out the cookies itself?

Comment: I did and it was no change from what it is now. It did not change how in operated in my two test cases at all (being cookie_jar contain no information when it printed, however if I get a website and then print, it contains a little bit of useless information and no new cookie file is created.)

Comment: So apparently index.dat is a hidden folder. I see it now (as well as several others in various locations on my computer). I see the website I am trying to find listed in the file as well. So I guess that line is correct and maybe it just isn't being parsed correctly. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With IE8 on my Windows XP system, cookies are in `C:\Documents and Settings\userid\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files`. There is no `index.dat`, the cookies are in their own files.

I don't know [where IE9 stores cookies](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/View-temporary-Internet-files-in-Internet-Explorer-9).

However, if you are trying to automate something on a site where users log on via IE, and start your program, you can use [Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aIE%3a%3aMechanize) or drive IE via [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aOLE). See, for example, my blog post [Using Win32::OLE with events to capture Internet Explorer screenshots with Perl](http://blog.nu42.com/2012/06/using-win32ole-with-events-to-capture.html) . Information on the methods, properties, and events available, see [InternetExplorer object documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29).

Comment: Hi there. I have no idea why, but `Win32::OLE` is giving me plenty of trouble with threads and events. I started trying `Win32::IEAutomation`, and it just can't seem to load Agent->Document and fails over and over. `Win32::IE::Mechanize` has failed on roughly half of it's test cases and won't install. After spending so much time on the others, I'm currently giving `Win32::IE::Mechanize` another shot at installing. (Also, the `index.dat` file was hidden and I had to select to show system files to see it. It may be there and you may just not have system files showing.)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `Win32::OLE` with Perl threads. Too much of a can of worms for me. Controlling IE via `Win32::OLE` has always worked for me. You really have to study the MSDN docs, however.